# How to find $\liminf f_n $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $$f_n  = \chi_{[n, n+1]} $$

We know $$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f_n dm = 1 $$for all $n$. However, I am a little unsure whether $\liminf f_n (= \lim f_n) = 0$ or $1$.  Can someone explain me the limit of this sequence of functions?

Comment: Are you looking for $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ or $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}f_n(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x \in \mathbb R$. Let $N \in \mathbb N, N > x$. Such $N$ always exists by the [Archimedean property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property). Since $x \not\in [N, N+1]$, we have $f_N(x) = 0$. This is also true for all $n \ge N$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = 0$.

Since the pointwise limit exists for all $x \in \mathbb R$, there is no need to investigate $\limsup$ or $\liminf$ separately. They are both equal to the limit $0$.

If you're still interested in evaluating $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$, notice that it's defined as
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{m \ge n}f_m(x).
$$

Again, if $m \ge n \ge N$, then $f_m(x) = 0$. Thus $\sup_{m \ge n} f_m(x) = 0$. It follows that the limit is $0$.

$\liminf$ can be handled similarly.

Answer (score 2):

$\liminf f_n = \chi _{\liminf [n,n+1]} = \chi_{\phi} = 0 $

$\limsup f_n = \chi _{\limsup [n,n+1]} = \chi_{\phi} = 0 $

Hence $\lim f_n = 0$